# HTML 5, HOWTO loading a picture of square or drawing a simple square, and rotate it at 45 degree

Tags: html, canvas

This should be simple.. but can't figure out :
I am using rotate function on the 1st rectangle, but i am getting the 2nd rectangle rotated ?? :( 
Updated the code after Remmy Sharp's answer. But now the box has disappeared. I simply want one of two boxes to rotate on their reg point.

Where is the problem ?

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      #myCanvas {
        border: 1px solid #9C9898;
      }
       #myCanvas2 {
        border: 1px solid #9C9898;
      }
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
    </style>
    <script>
      window.onload = function() {
        var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

        context.beginPath();
        context.rect(100, 100, 200, 100);
        context.fillStyle = '#8ED6FF';
        context.fill();
        context.lineWidth = 5;
        context.strokeStyle = 'black';
        context.stroke();
        context.rotate(20*Math.PI/180); //<<<1st rectange should rotate 

        var canvas2 = document.getElementById('myCanvas2');
        var context2 = canvas2.getContext('2d') //<< updated as per Remmy Sharp's answer.

        context2.beginPath();
        context2.rect(200, 200, 200, 100);
        context2.fillStyle = '#8ED6FF';
        context2.fill();
        context2.lineWidth = 5;
        context2.strokeStyle = 'black';
        context2.stroke();

        //canvas2.rotate = 45 
        //context2.rotate(20*Math.PI/180)
      };

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="500">

        <canvas id="myCanvas2"   width="400" height="200"></canvas>

    </canvas>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I guess you should `.rotate()` before `.stroke()` on rect. #1 and then reset the orientation before `.stroke()` on rect. #2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you're painting the canvas and the first rectangle when you do the first `context.stroke` - this immediately paints the pixels.

Then you're transforming the coordinate system with the `context.rotate`, and then any subsequent painting to the canvas uses the newly transformed coordinate system (and hence why the second paint is rotated).

And the *reason* the second rectangle is rotated (even though you appear to have a second canvas) is...you have a typo:

```
var context2 = canvas.getContext('2d');
```

Should read:

```
var context2 = canvas2.getContext('2d');
```

So `context2` is actually the same as your `context` variable in your example.

You'll also notice that when you update the code with the above fix, the rotation is too much - you'll want to translate the `0,0` centre point before rotating to get the effect (I think) you want.

**Edited and continue debugging code**

So there's a bunch more problems in your code including:

1. You've nested the second canvas *inside* the first - so the second doesn't really exist.
2. Your rotation was pretty big and I suspect not quite what you're after (like I said before, you probably want to rotate at 50/50 centre point, rather than 0,0).
3. Your canvas' are huge, and next to each other. So when you paint the second canvas - you can't see it *because it's off screen*.

Here's the code fixed, and made the canvas' smaller (and CSS bg of red so I could see them) and I added an animation to visualise the rotation on the second canvas: http://jsbin.com/ovefux/1/edit

Comment: ok, i changed to canvas2. Still not working. Actually now the box has disappeared. :(

Comment: I've updated the answer with both a working link, but also the other issues you had in the code.